# Check if a value in dataframe will increase or decrease a certain percentage

Tags: python, pandas, trading

I have an OHLC dataframe, e.g.:

| index | open | close | high | low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-23 10:00:00+00:00 | 1421.100 | 1424.500 | 1427.720 | 1422.650 |
| 2021-03-23 11:00:00+00:00 | 1424.500 | 1421.480 | 1422.400 | 1411.890 |
| 2021-03-23 12:00:00+00:00 | 1421.480 | 1435.170 | 1443.980 | 1433.780 |
| 2021-03-23 13:00:00+00:00 | 1435.170 | 1440.860 | 1443.190 | 1437.590 |
| 2021-03-23 14:00:00+00:00 | 1440.860 | 1438.920 | 1443.570 | 1435.200 |
| 2021-03-23 15:00:00+00:00 | 1438.920 | 1435.990 | 1444.840 | 1435.060 |
| 2021-03-23 16:00:00+00:00 | 1435.990 | 1441.920 | 1446.610 | 1441.450 |

Now I want to find out, if the price will first increase or decrease e.g. for 1%. What I have so far is the following working code:

```
def check(x):

    check = ohlc[ohlc.index > x.name]
    price = ohlc.at[x.name, 'close']

    high_thr = price * 1.01
    low_thr = price * 0.99

    high_indexes = check[check['high'] > high_thr]
    low_indexes = check[check['low'] < low_thr]

    if high_indexes.shape[0] > 0 and low_indexes.shape[0] > 0:

        high = high_indexes.index[0]
        low = low_indexes.index[0]

        if high < low:
            return 1
        elif high > low:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0


ohlc['check'] = ohlc.apply(find_threshold, axis=1)
```

This is extremely slow for larger datasets. Is there any other better way than iterating over every row, slicing and finding all indexes to get the nearest one?

Comment: Can you include your expected output? What is `find_threshold`? Your code cannot be run as is. The parameter in your `check` function is `x` but you also use `ohlc` within it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you trying to find volatility?  Are you trying to get one answer for the whole table that is 1 if the stock hit 1% below the closing price more often than it hit 1% above the closing price?

Comment: I want to find per each row, if in the future the row price will first be higher or lower a certain percentage. so if the price is now 1000, and three rows later high is 1011, it should return 1. if it stays between 991 and 1009 till 20 rows later, and then low is below 990, it should return -1.

Comment: Compare each row with the last row... The last comparison decide the value of the current row: -1, 0, 1. If your value is 1000 and the last row is 999, the final value should be 0 IIUC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is not too different from how you're doing it:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def check(x, change=0.01):
    time = x.name
    price = ohlc.loc[time, 'close']
    while True:
        if time not in ohlc.index:          # If we reach the end
            return 0
        high = ohlc.loc[time, 'high']
        low = ohlc.loc[time, 'low']
        if high > (1.0 + change) * price:   # Upper thresh broken
            return 1
        elif low < 1.0 - change) * price:   # Lower thresh broken
            return -1
        time = time + timedelta(hours=1)    # Time update

ohlc['check'] = ohlc.apply(check, axis=1)
```

If efficiency is what you're worreid about, applying this way is slightly more efficient because it only looks ahead as far as it needs to to break the threshold. Optionally, you could limit this to up to, say, 100 hours into the future by modifying the while loop, capping the number of checks per row to 100:

```
    endtime = time + timedelta(hours=100)
    while time < endtime:
        # etc
```

Comment: thanks, this is a lot faster. I had to move the time change to the beginning of the while loop, otherwise it will take high and low from the already closed row.